# A uniform sphere $V$ mass $M$ radius $a$. A unit point mass distance $b$ away. Then the gravitational on the point mass is $\frac{GM}{b^3}$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $V$ be a uniform solid sphere of mass $M$ and radius $a$. Place a unit point mass a distance $b$ from the center of $V$. Show that the gravitational attraction of $V$ on the point mass $\mbox{is}\ GM/b^{3}$.

I tried to calculate the $z$ component of the force. I used the triple integral

$$ \iiint G m_0 \left( \frac \delta { \rho ^ 3 } \right) \rho \cos ( \phi ) \rho ^ 2 \sin (\phi) \mathrm d \rho \mathrm d \phi \mathrm d \theta $$

$m_0$ = unit mass of $b$ = $1$

$\delta$ = density of $V$ = Mass / volume = $\frac M {\frac43\pi a^3}$ (I think this makes sense)

$\rho$ is distance from $O$

simplified to:
$$ \frac M {\frac43\pi a^3} G \iiint \cos ( \phi ) \sin (\phi) \mathrm d \rho \mathrm d \phi \mathrm d \theta $$

If that's right, great.

The bounds are hard for me.

$0$ to $2\pi$ for $\theta$

$0$ to some angle $\alpha$ for $\phi$?

Idk what to do for $\rho$ or $\phi$ but I tried several ways.

Question 5C-6* https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-a-triple-integrals/problem-set-10/MIT18_02SC_SupProb5.pdf

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6scCK.jpg)

Comment: Please format equations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Also, are you allowed to use [Gauss' Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_law_for_gravity) or the [Shell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem)?

Comment: @Sandejo The exercise requires triple integrals in spherical coordinates, without those.

Comment: What is the "gravitational attraction"? The force? The acceleration? No, both of those things are vectors. The magnitude of the force, or the magnitude of the acceleration? Also your question title is missing a word after "gravitational".

Comment: @Myridium The exercise is asking me to find the z component of the force vector

Comment: @RenzoM-Svartz please clarify in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Is the point mass inside or outside of the sphere?

Comment: For $\rho$, the bounds should be from $0$ to $b$

Comment: @Myridium I pasted the question from the exercises from MIT's OCW.

Comment: @CSquared Thanks. I'm hoping someone can give me a more detailed explanation.

Comment: This is plain wrong. When $b\ge a$, the answer is $GM/b^2$. When $b<a$, the force is *linear* in $b$.